# Extracting gzip file in an S3 bucket to another S3 Bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip

im trying to copy the gzip file from one S3 bucket and extract its content to another S3 bucket using gzip library.
im getting an error

> Seek from end not supported

```
import boto3, json
from io import BytesIO
import gzip

def lambda_handler():
    try:
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        copy_source = {
            'Bucket': 'srcbucket',
            'Key': 'samp.gz'
            }
        bucket = s3.Bucket('destbucket')
        bucketSrc = s3.Bucket('srcbucket')

        s3Client = boto3.client('s3', use_ssl=False)

        s3Client.upload_fileobj(                      # upload a new obj to s3
            Fileobj=gzip.GzipFile(              # read in the output of gzip -d
                None,                           # just return output as BytesIO
                'rb',                           # read binary
                fileobj=BytesIO(s3Client.get_object(Bucket='srcbucket', Key='samp.gz')['Body'].read())),
            Bucket='destbucket',                      # target bucket, writing to
            Key="")               # target key, writing to

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Not that it's relevant to the issue you're facing, but why would you set `use_ssl=False`?

Comment: i picked an example from so, it doesnot matter if the variable is true/false, its failing and im not able to figure it out

Comment: You should not suppress SSL. That aside, how are you expecting this code to work? Does this zip file always have exactly one file in it? Also, the upload_fileobj method requires a key, and you've supplied empty string. How is that going to work?

Comment: Please try to minimize your example. There are _even_ and _context_ variables which are unused and have no meaning for the question. Also you don't have to catch exception in the example - we will see it on console when calling code inside.

Comment: @jarmod i tried providing a key and creating a folder in the destination bucket, i was trying to extract the whole contents of zip file to destination bucket.

Comment: @ŁukaszŚlusarczyk - i was trying to execute the code from lambda, removed the function parameters

Comment: You're going to have to either unzip the entire ZIP file to Lambda local disk (which has a limit of 512MB) then upload file by file, or stream the contents of the ZIP file into memory, file by file, and then upload each stream to S3). And you will need to supply an appropriate key for each and every upload.

Comment: @jarmod thanks, i tried it that way, its working now

Answer (score 0):

You can't unzip the ZIP file and upload its constituent files the way you're trying to.

You could unzip the entire ZIP file to Lambda local disk in `/tmp` (note this has a limit of 512MB diskspace) then upload file by file. Or, if it will not fit on disk or you prefer not to persist to desk, then you can stream the contents of the ZIP file into memory, file by file, and then upload each stream to S3). In both solutions, you will need to supply an appropriate key for each and every upload.